# График функции для Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, lazarus

Я до этого не сталкивался с Delphi, но прочитав некоторые источники немного понял как работать с формой. У меня проблема с постройкой графика **ArcCos**. Я не могу понять почему компилятор ругаеться из за названия

```
    function f1(a:real):real;
 begin
   result:= ArcCos(a);
 end;

 { TForm1 }

 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var x,a,b,h:real;
   i,N:integer;
   begin
     CheckListBox1.Checked[0] := true;
     Series1.Clear;
     a:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
     b:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
     N:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
     h:=(b-a)/N;
     for i:=0 to N do begin
       x:=a+h*i;
       Series1.AddXY(x,f1(x),'',clRed);
     end;
   end;

procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[0] then Series1.Active := true
    else Series1.Active := false;
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  begin
    case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of 0:Chart1.View3D := false;
    1:Chart1.View3D := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

В момент компиляции выходит ошибка что нет такого ArcCos, нет Series1( Я эго тоже искал в параметрах Tchart, но не нашёл), и нет Viev3D. Если есть возможность буду рад видеть сразу исправленый код

Comment: чтобы series1 появилось ее надо создать на графике видимо. view3D возможно не поддерживается либо из-за ограниченного набора функций стандартного teechart, либо из-за древности версии делфей. на arrcos  ругается вероятно потому что не подключен модуль math.

Comment: Я пытался создать как в инструкции говорили, типу найти Series в TChar потом add и добавить Line, но там так и не появилось значение Series для Line

Comment: Исправил ошибку ArcCos, подключил Math

Comment: Приведите текст интерфейса юнита, станет значительно понятнее, где искать ошибку

Comment: @Олег Вы решили свои проблемы?

Comment: @MBo Добрый день, пока нет, искал в Интернете варианты.
   
Compile Project, Target: laba9.exe: Exit code 1, Errors: 6 unit1.pas(58,6) Error: Identifier not found "Series1" unit1.pas(65,8) Error: Identifier not found "Series1" unit1.pas(78,38) Error: Identifier not found "Series1" unit1.pas(79,10) Error: Identifier not found "Series1" unit1.pas(91,44) Error: identifier idents no member "View3D" unit1.pas(92,14) Error: identifier idents no member "View3D"
Это то что выдает компилятор

Comment: Я ещё думаю может проблема в Лазарусе, может в нём нет необходимых елементов

Comment: Вы же даже не написали про Лазарус, упоминали только Delphi

Comment: @MBo Я ж не думал что проблема в программе, думал что код не тот